# How to get the DHCP-controlled DNS domain name for my Ubuntu machines in a Windows network?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, domain-name-system, dhcp

I've been going in circles for a while trying to figure this out. I have a number of Ubuntu machines (some virtual) on a Windows network. From a Windows machine, I can `ping` or `nslookup` the Ubuntu machines, but not the reverse unless the Ubuntu machines specify fully qualified DNS names. But I can't seem to get the qualification suffix from the Ubuntu environment.

An example will clarify what is going on. Assume the Windows machine is called `Win1`, the Ubuntu machine `Ubu1`, and the network suffix is `.notlocalatall`.

```
On Win1:
$ echo %USERDNSDOMAINNAME%
notlocalatall
$ nslookup Ubu1
[...]
Name:    Ubu1.notlocalatall
Address: 131.132.32.14
$ nslookup Ubu1.notlocalatall
[...]
Name:    Ubu1.notlocalatall
Address: 131.132.32.14
$ ping Ubu1
[works normally, with 0% packet loss]
$ ping Ubu1.notlocalatall
[works normally, with 0% packet loss]
```

---

```
On Ubu1:
$ hostname -d
[blank]
$ nslookup Win1
[...]
** server can't find Win1: SERVFAIL
$ nslookup Win1.notlocalatall
[...]
Name:    Win1.notlocalatall
Address: 131.132.32.167
$ ping Win1
ping: unknown host Win1
$ ping Win1.notlocalatall
[works normally, with 0% packet loss]
```

For `ssh` purposes, I could live with having to specify the DNS suffix, but I need to get it from some command or bit of script.

And no, the solution is not to edit `/etc/hosts`, because the whole thing runs under DHCP.

`Ubu1` is running Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS and the Network control panel's Options: IPv4 Parameters are set to "Automatic (DHCP)".

Comment: On the Ubuntu client side, you can try this:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/52001/adding-additional-dns-search-domains-when-using-dhcp

Comment: That was it! I edited my networking connection to specify the suffix as the search domain, and now `nslookup` works the same with and without the suffix.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/52001/adding-additional-dns-search-domains-when-using-dhcp Use Jim Hume's answer, currently the second one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your DHCP server so it set on the DHCP client the domain-search

http://linux.die.net/man/5/dhcp-options

> option domain-search domain-list; The domain-search option specifies a
>   'search list' of Domain Names to be used by the client to locate
>   not-fully-qualified domain names. The difference between this option
>   and historic use of the domain-name option for the same ends is that
>   this option is encoded in RFC1035 compressed labels on the wire. For
>   example:
>
> option domain-search "example.com", "sales.example.com",
>                        "eng.example.com";

This way when you perform an nslookup it will try with all the specified domains until it finds a valid response (or until loop through all them).

So if you perform `nslookup server1` if will try to query dns for

1. server1.example.com
2. server1.sales.example.com
3. eng.example.com

Comment: I cannot configure the DHCP server. I can configure the Ubuntu clients, however. Could you give an actual example of the command line expected? Something like `$ sudo dhclient option domain-search "notlocalatall"`, I suppose?

Comment: You can try this http://askubuntu.com/a/141193

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. Jim Hurne's answer, right below the one at the other end of that link, turns out to be the right one.